# Performing PCA on spectral bands - satellite image

Tags: python, image, pca, satellite-image

I am working on an excercise in  remote sensing, and have some trouble performing a pca. I have 103 different spectral bands, meaning the shape of my array is (m, n, 103). I want to reduce this to ten components.

I tried to use PCA from sklearn.decomposition, however my dimensions are wrong, and i dont think i understand how to use the function.

`pca = PCA(n_components = 10)`
 `test = feature_scaling(data)`
 `pca_components = pca.fit_transform(test)`

Giving me the following error: *** ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.

I was wondering if i maybe need to extract each of the spectral bands and perform a flattening, but i am not sure what my input in the pca is supposed to look like.

Does anyone know what i can do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: does this help ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62583863/how-can-i-apply-pca-dimensionality-reduction-to-a-3d-matrix